# How to show the latest post (one only) on the homepage with full text, comments and all?

Tags: wordpress, blog-post

On Wordpress, how can I show the latest post (one only) on the homepage with full text, comments and all?

I basically would like the homepage to be the latest post as if I clicked it and got the post url (like: `domain/wordpress/?p=18` for example).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

- In your WordPress admin panel, under
  Settings in the sidebar, click
  Reading.
- Make sure the top radio button under
  Front Page Displays ("Your latest
  posts") is selected.
- Now change the number in the box next
  to "Blog pages show at most" to 1.
- Now, make sure that the "Full text"
  radio button next to "For each
  article in a feed, show" is selected.

That should do the trick, but let me know if it doesn't work for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for the reply. I did what you've suggested TheLibzter :-)
windyjonas, your answer was partial right. What eventually did the trick is:

```
<?php query_posts(); ?>
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
   <h2>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
      <?php the_title(); ?>
     </a>
   </h2>
   <div class="entry"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php
  global $withcomments; $withcomments = true;
  comments_template( '', true );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect from home.php:

```
if (have_posts()):
    while (have_posts()):
        the_post();
        wp_redirect(get_permalink());
    endwhile;
endif;
```